# Variable value transfered from Model to ViewModel is not showing on View

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I'm learning WPF MVVM and I get stuck with one problem. I'm calculating variable value in one class every 200ms, then I'm sending it to ViewModel where PropertyChanged event is fired, but the value did not appear on View. When I copy this code for calculation of variable value to ViewModel constructor then everything is working. Could you give me some hints what am I doing wrong?

Class where I calculate values:

```
public class CalculatingSecondsTask
{
    public string seconds { get; set; }

    public CalculatingSecondsTask()
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            int i = 0;

            while (true)
            {
                await Task.Delay(200);
                seconds = (i++).ToString();

                UpdateSecondsInViewModel(seconds);                    
            }

        });
    }

    public void UpdateSecondsInViewModel(string secs)
    {
        ViewModel test = new ViewModel();
        test.Seconds_To_Start = secs;
    }
```

My ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string mSeconds_To_Start;          
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;        

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (propertyName == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyExpression");

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }       
    }        

    public string Seconds_To_Start
    {
        get
        {                
            return mSeconds_To_Start;
        }

        set
        {              
            mSeconds_To_Start = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Seconds_To_Start));                                                
        }
    }
```

And my View is like:

```
<Window x:Class="Program.Views.StartWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Program.Views"
    xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:Program.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Program" Height="110" Width="400">
<Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>             

        <!-- Text -->
        <TextBlock x:Name="Seconds_To_Start"  HorizontalAlignment="Center">                    
            <Run Text="{Binding Seconds_To_Start}" />
            <Run Text="seconds" />
        </TextBlock>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: you create a new view model every 0.2 sec (`ViewModel test = new ViewModel();`). View happily works with another single instance of a view model (`<ViewModel:ViewModel/>`). Nothing changes in that single instance.

Comment: Besides that, `Task.Run(async () => { ... })` doesn't seem to make much sense. Move that out of the constructor into an async method.

Comment: How can I pass the seconds value to the proper instance of ViewModel then?

Comment: Throw away the CalculatingSecondsTask class, and add a DispatcherTimer to your ViewModel class. In its Tick handler, update the Seconds_To_Start property.

Comment: Yes, then it will work - I already done that before. But the clue of my learning program now is to learn how to send variables values from Model to ViewModel and then displaying it on View. So, according to ASh answer, my question is now how can I refer to proper instance of ViewModel from the Model?

Comment: You've assigned a ViewModel instance to the MainWindow's DataContext in XAML. So you should access that in your code, e.g. by `var vm = (ViewModel)Application.Current.MainWindow.DataContext;`

Comment: Thank you Clemens, but when I used this in my UpdateSecondsInViewModel class then I'm getting 'error CS0119: 'Application' is a type, which is not valid in the given context'. Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?